# jQuery each() and if statement only working for first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple piece of jQuery code

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#line_items_table tr').each( function () {
    var self = $(this);
    console.log(parseInt(self.attr('data-id')));
    if ( !$.inArray( parseInt(self.attr('data-id')), errors )) {
      console.log("inside conditional");
      self.addClass('incorrect_item');
    }
  });
});
```

With `errors = [19,20,21]`, i get this output

```
3417
3419
"inside conditional"
3420
3421
3422 
3423 
3424 
3425
```

And `errors = [20,21]`, this output:

```
3417
3419
3420
"inside conditional"
3421
3422
3423
3424
3425
```

Why is this only working for the first element??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `$.inArray`, always check for `-1`, not just true or false

```
if ( $.inArray( parseInt(self.data('id'), 10), errors ) == -1 ) {
```

The reason is that `$.inArray` return the index of the found value, and for the first item that index is `0`, which is falsy, and that's the reason it only works on the first one.

Comment: pleas can you explain why to check -1

Comment: *The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match* - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/